# How do I force Azure AD MFA prompt for WInForms application logins?

Tags: .net, winforms, azure-active-directory, multi-factor-authentication

I have a .Net Winforms desktop application. I'm authenticating users through Azure Active Directory. Individual AD users have MFA enabled.

I'm using the following code snippet for authenication within my code:

```
var builder = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
             .Create(AzureADAuthentication.ClientId)
             .WithAuthority(AzureADAuthentication.Instance + AzureADAuthentication.Tenant)
             .WithDefaultRedirectUri();

builder.WithWindowsBroker();
PublicClientApp = builder.Build();

authResult = await PublicClientApp
                  .AcquireTokenInteractive((IEnumerable<string>) scopes)
                  .WithParentActivityOrWindow(parentForm.Handle)
                  .WithPrompt(Prompt.NoPrompt)
                  .WithLoginHint(loginHint)
                  .ExecuteAsync();
```

Is there a way that I can enforce MFA login, either once a day or perhaps even every login?
There seems to be some default period/interval for which a login will remain valid.
So I if login/shut own the application successive times, I'm not getting MFA prompts.

Is there a way to force MFA during App login?

Comment: The best I could figure out so far is to set the cache  through Azure->AD->Security->MFA->Additional Cloud Based MFA Settings->remember multi-factor authentication on trusted device. By enabling this setting and and setting the timeout to 1 day, I can at least force MFA authentication once a day. But what we really need is prompt on every login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably have another task somewhere (or in the App.Exit event) that would clear the token auth cache by using **GetAccountsAsync** and loop them calling **RemoveAsync** to clear the cache.

If your routine works right, it should prompt after doing that.

You might also achieve the same by changing the Prompt enum into **ForceLogin** or **ChooseAccount**

References:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identity.client.prompt?view=azure-dotnet
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identity.client.publicclientapplication?view=azure-dotnet

Comment: I am already doing auth cache clean up via GetAccountsAsync()/RemoveAsnc().
I've tried using ForceLogin, ChooseAccount, NoPrompt enums for WithPrompt() call.
I still get the same results. I get the desired MFA challenge on initial log in.
On subsequent logins, I no longer get prompted. If I come back a day or so later, I get the desired prompt/challenge. 

It feels to me like that there is some cache period setting somewhere within Azure/AD?
I really would like to get MFA challenge on every login. How do I do that?